# The pen of Surface Pro 3 doesn't distinguish between writing and selecting

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface-pro-3, handwriting-recognition

I have a problem with the pen with Surface Pro 3 and `OneNote 2013`(desktop version).  The pen worked normally until recently when it stopped properly distinguishing between writing and selecting.  For example when I want to write the word “who”, after I write “w” and pick up the pen tip to write  “h”, the pen transforms from writing to selecting and I can’t continue to write.

I updated my Windows and my MS Office with Windows Update, and I obtained the updates for OneNote manually and installed them, but that didn't solve the problem.

I don’t have this problem in the Metro version of OneNote. However, the Metro version doesn't have some feature such as search in handwriting content or save the documents locally. So I'd like to use the desktop version.

I installed the OneNote 2010 desktop version, too, but that has the same problem.

OS: Windows 8.1 64Bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved after I upgrade my Surface Pro 3 OS (Windows 8.1 64Bit) to windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the new ink API that Windows is implementing. Microsoft wants a pen/stylus to work as that, and touch is to replace the mouse. This will be the same in all Office applications when 2016 arrives.

Comment: Can you explain how to use it to write individual words without it switching to selection mode?

Comment: Just tap on the screen and you get the text insertion cursor, on the desktop version I think you also need to tap the keyboard icon if you want to use the soft keyboard.